# How to change process variable value through remote rest api call for current human task in jbpm 6.5.0Final

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbpm, redhat-bpm

I have a many human task. After start the process i want to update some process variable value with rest API call that's relates to current task. If anyone knows how to do that commend bellow.

> I try with `/execute` this is only start the task then how to update the process variable for already started process instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation

Here is how to do update the process variable. However, this will update an entire process rather than only that specific task.

```
server/containers/{id}/processes/instances/{pInstanceId}/variables - POST
```

If you want to update process variable from a task, you should do it during task completion. However, this requires you to have output variables from that task. Otherwise, it won't take any effect.

```
server/containers/{id}/tasks/{tInstanceId}/states/completed - PUT
```

Anyway, the full documentation of rest can be viewed in

```
{localhost}:{port}/kie-server/docs
```

Comment: Hi @hnandarusdy, thanks for yout reply. I'm using `http://uname:pwd@172.17.0.3:8080/jbpm-console/rest/' ` i can able to get variable value through `curl -X GET 'http://uname:pwd@172.17.0.3:8080/jbpm-console/rest/runtime/{deploymentId}/process/instance/164896/variable/work' ` but  i can't set back that variable.

Comment: I see... I am not really sure if it is through jbpm-console. I thought you would deploy the kie-server also. Have a try this http://host:port/jbpm-console/rest/task/<taskID>/complete?<variable>=<variable value>
 from this link: https://aboullaite.me/using-jbpms-restful-api/ (I have never tried my self as I used kie server)

Comment: while completing the current task we can update but my situation is task still running I want to update some process variable value through jbpm-console/rest API call.